# Using a similar application essay I used before

Tags: ethics, application, united-states, plagiarism, bachelor

I recently submitted an application essay for a pre-college program, and was accepted. I'm particularly proud of my essay; I put my best into it.

Now, after the pre-college program, I intend to apply for one of the institute's degree programs.

I've written an essay for the application. Most of it is rewritten, but it does have a lot of similarities (the intro paragraph is nearly identical).

> **Would it be considered plagiarism for using my own work? If not, is it still frowned upon if there are many similarities, and could impact my chances of getting accepted?**

I understand that it is likely that answers are individual to each institute, but I'd like to know what the general answer is.

I've read some sources that claim students applying to multiple schools use very similar essays for all (assuming the prompts are similar), only changing statements specific to each school. So, maybe it is alright that I do such a thing? But then again, this is the same institute I'm applying to.

Comment: It's not plagiarism.  These essays are not published.  Thank you for asking, though!  It's good to be careful.

Comment: However, this site is not for undergrad questions, so I will vote to close.

Comment: @aparente001 - Discrimination against youngsters? `:)` Sorry, though; I didn't realize that undergrads couldn't ask (even though there is a `bachelor` tag). Is there a site that does cater to undergrads?

Comment: @aparente001 - Thanks for the answer. For secondary (well, more likely primary) opinion, I contacted admissions, and they said that they didn't mind, as long as it followed the prompt.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make the rules.  Also, sorry, I don't know another site to point you to.  Note for future use, it is sometimes possible for an undergrad to ask a question in a way that will be useful to people other than undergraduates, and such a question is likely to be accepted and answered.

Comment: @aparente001 - Alright, thanks. Should I delete the question (given it violates a rule), or is it worth keeping?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  You could search for that on Academia Meta and if you don't find it you could ask.  On the other hand I have occasionally deleted a question or an answer I had written, and nobody seemed to mind.  I guess it comes down to whether you think the Question and Comment might be useful to others.  I think maybe yes.  Which is partly why I wrote my comment for you.

Comment: @aparente001 - OK, I'll keep it. Thanks, though!

Comment: If the question was to re-use parts of an essay in a grad school application, I believe that would be on topic here, but I don't know if that would be as useful as norms between grad school applications and undergrad applications might not be very related.

Comment: @aparente001 This site _is_ for undergraduate questions that can be generalized to graduate courses. Please, don't vote to close automatically. See also this meta discussion: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/3300/20058

Comment: @SirJony - Sorry!  I am clearly not an expert on finding this fine lines.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly think there is nothing wrong in applying with a similar work of yours. And I think it, well, for all the reasons you've mentioned yourself, starting with the fact that it won't be considered as plagiarism, since the primary version of it is yours as well, ending with the fact that the work is sent to the same school.
However, depending on whether you've made only minor changes to it or not, you might adjust the work a bit more, or expand it, or formulate some thoughts differently for the sake of back-up (say, if there is a chance that any of the members of the admissions know or have previously seen your primary work - then they might think that you weren't generous on the effort and,therefore, don't perceive the opportunity to be worth working more on that work or on additional ideas). After all, you're the creator, so it is still up to you to decide upon all the abovementioned things!

Answer (score 0):

**Plagiarism** of one's own work is a contradiction in terms. It does not exist. However, **duplicate publication** is rightfully frowned upon, unless made explicit. **Parallel grant application** is allowed by some funding bodies and disallowed by others. Even if disallowed, the same application materials may be reused later. **Parallel job or stipend applications** are taken for granted, and it is perfectly acceptable to reuse the application materials. Whether it is also prudent is another matter. Applications are much more likely to succeed if they are tailored to the position.

Comment: There is self-plagiarism. I think it's stupid and doesn't make sense but it's actually a thing.